# Android Wear Obfuscated Crash

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, wear-os

I've recently added Wear functionality to one of my apps, and I started seeing an obfuscated crash being reported. I've updated the app a few times since then, which included using newer Google Play Service versions. Here's the crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.aa.f()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.r.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.bl()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$2.onConnected()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.r.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.r.x()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.q$g.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.q$g.d()
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.q$b.bQ()
```

I've looked at any place in my code that uses `onConnected`, and I can't find anything that would cause an ISE. Anyone see anything like this, or know what it is?

Comment: Did you add the Proguard exceptions for GPlayServices to your proguard-file? Just asking since you haven't mentioned it. (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard)

Comment: I don't use proguard. Do I still need to add these exceptions?

Comment: Nope. If you add `runProguard false` to your `build.gradle` file Proguard won't run and obfuscate the code.

Comment: I have that in my build.gradle. In any case, how am I supposed to fix something like this?